# Magento 1: Where is oauth_admin.php

Tags: magento-1, rest-api, oauth

The [rest documentation for Magento 1](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) make mention of an `oauth_admin.php` file

```
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://yourhost/admin/oAuth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://yourhost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://yourhost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';
```

This appears to be the file/URL that oauth will redirect to after the *User Authorization* step.

The docs fails to clearly say **what** this `oauth_admin.php` program/script needs to do with the `oauth_token` and and `oauth_verifier` variables it receives in order to work with the rest of the code sample.

Does this file exist anywhere in the docs and/or elsewhere?  If not is there known science for getting Magento 1's three legged oauth working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oauth_admin.php` is just a stand-alone PHP Oauth client script which can be your `callbackurl`. You can replace this with your `controller and action url path`. Its involved in all the three legged authentication.

So the very file which you have pasted and [find here in the doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) is the actual `oauth_admin.php`

**A quick overview of the Three legged authentication in this file**

> 1. Get the initial temporary request token.

```
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug(); 

    // it returns an array with two values oauth_token (request token) and oauth_token_secret , eventually both of these will be used to get the access token and secret
    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
```

> 2. Validate and confirm / reject the admin Oauth authorization request.

```
   // where $adminAuthorizationUrl is http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize and oauth_token is the request token
   header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
```

> 3. Exchange the temporary request token and secret to get the final access token and secret, which enables the user to access the
>      resources they are allowed to access.

```
     $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
     $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
```

In this script, you can find the values are persisted in the session to remember the authentication step and the request and access tokens with their secret tokens.

Similar to the admin user, the customer is also allowed to access the resources allowed for them. In this case, only the authorization url is different `http://magentohost/oauth/authorize`

> `Mage_Oauth` module handles all the Oauth requests and responds
>   appropriately.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you.  I had thought of the sample program as "the code doing the requesting" and the callback URL as "the program that redirects back to the the program that needs the keys".  I wasn't obvious (until you stated so) that Magento's sample program is written in such a way that it's just a simple program handling everything.

Comment: no problem am glad that my answer clarifies...Yes i do agree the document was not so explicit to give the reader more clarity...i'll edit this on github to add more clarity to the further readers of this.

Comment: just made a pull request https://github.com/magento/devdocs-m1/pull/25 to the M1.x Dev Docs

Answer (score 1):

The oauth_token and oath_verifier is used to retrieve the oath_access_token 
That will be used for your subsequent requests to query products etc.

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$middleware = new Oauth1([
    'callback' => 'https://myapp.dev/not-magento-url/',
    'consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'consumer_secret' => $consumerSecret,
    'token' => $token,
    'token_secret' => $tokenSecret,
    'verifier' => $verifier,
]);

$stack->push($middleware);

// Client here is a GuzzleHttp\Client
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $magentoApiBaseUrl,
    'handler' => $stack,
]);

$response = $client->post('oauth/token', [
    'auth' => 'oauth',
    'allow_redirects' => true,
]);

// response should contain the access token / details needed
```